# css hover is not working for precedent elemts

Tags: html, css, web, hover

I want to change another element property on hover of a element. So far I've I came up with the following CSS:

```
#test3:hover #test4
{
background-color: red;
}

<div id="test3">three</div>
<div id="test4">four</div>
```

However, this is not working. Is this possible at all? What would you suggest?

Comment: #test3:hover + #test4 will work, but i recomend you to use javascript/jquery it will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#test3:hover #test4
```

This means, target an element `test4` that is a child of `test3`. You want the `+` [sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) instead:

```
#test3:hover + #test4
{
background-color: red;
}
```

[Browser compatibility table](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector#compatibilitysection)

Comment: @Sri what exactly is your requirement?